# Converting date to epoch date - Runs slower

Tags: performance, unix, awk, epoch

I have a log file of the format

```
RESPONSE1: Sat Aug 29 07:25:06 EDT 2015: oltp: response | {"status":"success"}|123457 | CCT | 6
RESPONSE1: Sat Aug 29 07:25:07 EDT 2015: oltp: response | {"status":"fail"}|123437 | CCT |
```

Each field is pipe delimited and I need to find certain KPI between two timestamps.

My approach is to first convert the Timestamp in UnixTime and then use it for comparison. When I do this, my awk commands goes very slow

I am using this way. My goal is only to do this way

1. Pick the date from 1st column, convert it to epoch date
2. Print the epoch along with the 5th column

But this runs very slow.

`awk -F "|" '$5>0 {print $1"|"$5}' ${logfilename} | sed -e "s/RESPONSE1: //g" -e "s/: oltp:/|/g" | awk -F "|" '{t=$1;"date -d \""t"\" +%s" | getline d; close("date -d \""t"\" +%s"); print d,$2}'`

Any help here to make this faster would be good. Each log file is very huge and I need to do this on at-least 5 to 6 log files, thus making it very slow

Let me know if the approach is correct.

Comment: No, the approach is wrong. Edit your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input and tell us whether or not you have or can install GNU awk (run `awk --version`) so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to efficiently print the time in epoch secs plus the value of the 5th field using GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=" *[|] *"
    for (i=1;i<=12;i++) {
        m[substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(i-1)*3+1,3)] = i
    }
}
{
    split($1,t,/[ :]+/)
    print mktime(t[9]" "m[t[3]]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6]" "t[7]), $5
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1440851106 6
1440851107
```

but you haven't shown us what it is you're trying to do with that info so we can't help you any further.